# Etymology of 'kinematics'

Tags: etymology

What is the etymology of the word 'kinematics' - the maths of movement, not taking into account physical forces such as friction and air resistance.

I was speaking with a friend about it and suggested that it comes from the two words: kinetic (essentially meaning movement) and mathematics. These 2 words seemed to go together well to make 'kinematics', and seemed a liable suggestion as kinematics is the mathematics of movement.

He laughed at me and said "That's ridiculous, no words come from just putting 2 words together".

So, what is the etymology of kinematics?

And just so that when I next see him I can give him some words that were made from 2 being put together, it would be lovely if you could throw a few into your answer.

Comment: No words come from just putting two words together, he says? Show him [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_portmanteaus). Or just ask him if he's ever heard the word "Microsoft". Or *cupboard*.

Comment: I know, he's being stupid, I know full well there are hundreds.

Comment: Anyway, http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=kinematics

Comment: I don't see the point of this question. What's so hard to understand about the etymology? The idea that "kinetic" and "mathematics" might be some kind of [portmanteau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) really is a non-starter once you look in an etymological dictionary. TLDR - General Reference.

Comment: Poor research. Voting to close as GR.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Etymonline for *[kinematics](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=kinematics)* shows

> “science of motion,” 1840, from Fr. cinématique (Ampère, 1834), from Gk. kinesis “movement, motion” (see [cite](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cite&allowed_in_frame=0)). Related: Kinematic (1864); kinematical.

That is, in 1834 Ampère coined (or used) the French term *cinématique*, which was adopted into English as  *kinematics* ca. 1840.  Note, the entry for *cite* refers to Greek  *kinein*,  “to move”.

Under Kinematics, OED cited Whewell, 1840: “M. Ampère, in his Essai sur la Philosophie des Sciences (1834)..proposes to term it Kinematics (*Cinématique*)” and Thomson & Tait, 1879: “We adopt the suggestion of Ampere and use the term Kinematics for the purely geometrical science of motion in the abstract.”

*Kinematics* thus sprang into being as a single word, or perhaps as a root plus a suffix. In English, suffix *[-ic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ic#Suffix)* is  “Used to form adjectives from nouns with the meaning "of or pertaining to"”.  However, *kinematics* came from the French with a *-tique* suffix already in use, so *-tics* was an English adaptation rather than addition to the word.

Comment: Not sure I really understand that...

Comment: Okay, I do now, do you know how Ampere came to cinematique? If you know any French you might be able to tell me the etymology of cinematique

Comment: @OllyPrice As jwpat7 mentions in his answer, [cinema](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cinema&allowed_in_frame=0) comes from the same Greek root. Also, *cinematography*: "from Greek: κίνημα, kinema 'movement' and γράφειν, graphein 'to record'". Note that *kinema* lends itself to *kinematic* the way *charisma* gives us *charismatic* ([Greek words ending in *-ma*](http://lists.ibiblio.org/pipermail/b-greek/2006-June/039027.html)).

Comment: @Olly, I don't know.  It seems difficult to find that etymology because the word *cinématique* in its  kinematics sense is overpowered, among web pages, by use in its French-cinema sense.

Comment: @Zairja so there's not actually a second word that creates the matics part of kinematics?

Comment: @OllyPrice Correct. We're adding the suffix *-ics* ("study of") to *kinema*. You can read about the *-ic* and *-tic* [suffixes](http://students.washington.edu/nwk/clas205/suffixes.html).

Answer (score 2):

It's a direct derivation from the Greek, though it wasn't coined till the 19th century. The Greek for 'motion' is *kinema* from the root verb *kineein*, and *-ic* (or *-tic* after a vowel) is a common way of forming adjectives both in Greek and in English. Certainly *kinetics* would have been a simpler word for this new-fangled 'science of motion'; but the word was already taken. It does appear that Ampere was the first to name the science, as 'cinematique'; English scientists preferred the version/translation *kinematics*.

(*Kinematograph* was a similar coinage, to describe 'moving pictures', and both that and its abbreviation *kinema* are common in the literature of the period. It seems that what determined the modern *cinema* for one and *kinematics* for the other may have been simply that there were more scientific pioneers of photography who spoke French, and more scientists of motion who spoke English.)