# What did "cinema" mean before cinema was invented?

Tags: meaning

I was attempting to find out the other day why *cinema* is spelt with a 'c' and not a 'k', as its etymology would seem to require. While doing so I noticed that the word *cinema* was used long before it could have had the current meaning, because *cinema* hadn't been invented. See [here](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cinema&year_start=1700&year_end=1900&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=):-

[image]

Looking for definitions in the online dictionaries turned up the current meaning, variously dated [C19](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cinema), [1895-1900](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cinema) or [1909](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cinema), and no other meaning.

So what did *cinema* mean in the earlier 19th Century, and briefly around 1705?

Comment: Looking at the 1705 to 1710 books, 2 are unavailable (so possibly could have *cinema* in them) and the other two don't have the word cinema in them. I think the early peak in the ngram is a mistake.

Comment: If you search within the single book representing the 1705 result, *cinema* doesn't appear. It's probably an OCR error or an indexing issue: Google Books isn't 100% reliable. Note too that the height of the spike is ***relative***: there are fewer books to search, so a single result yields a greater percentage. By 1900, there are millions of books and the number containing *cinema* represents a smaller percentage. (You probably knew that, but it's worth saying)

Comment: Searching before 1800 usually produces artefactual result like this. 1800 is a good cutoff date becauſe long S diſappeared about that time, and all S's became recognizable by OCR, inſtead of being detected as F's everywhere except at the ends of words.

Comment: I just checked through a print copy of the OED and it had no entry for Cinema but it did say this "Cinematic, -al, var of Kinematic -al, 1883 Athenium 3 Mar 281/3 Kinematics, or as it used to be called, cinematics, the name having been translated from the French cinematique, is the geometry of motion" so I guess (guess) that pre-cinema, the term referred to a field of math if it existed.

Comment: Your question is intriguing because I never gave it a thought before that the Germans (in my highschool German book) called the movie theater ***"Kino"***.

Comment: In physics course, you may have a unit on *kinematics*.  Which studies and describes motion, I guess.  The opposite would be *statics*, where you study or describe things not in motion, or where the motion is irrelevant.

Comment: @KristinaLopez - kino is Greek for movement, the french inventors of cinematography adapted it for french pronunciation. Either the Germans felt that Kino fitted their language better, wanted to be closer to the original Greek, or didn't want to admit that it was a French idea!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess would be an early version of *kinematics*, before the spelling settled down; see [Etymology of 'kinematics'](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/81540/8019). (That only began around 1840, but as others have said, pre-19th century Google Books results are unreliable: all those steam-driven computers.)